# animation points in OpenGL with C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opengl, opengl-3

I try in 3D but i am a beginner, so i try do with 2D first and value of z = 0. I have an array of points with values random in array points[] using std::vector. I have functions Distance(...) and CaculateF(...) to caculate new value for points[] and store in array pnew[]. I need draw points[] and move them to the value of pnew[], but i only know drawing random points in array points[] first, i can't move them exactly to values in pnew[]. Can anybody help me?!

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<glut.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<omp.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

struct Point
{
    float x, y , z;
    float vx, vy, vz; 
    unsigned long m;
    unsigned char r, g, b, a;
};
vector< Point > points, pnew;

void animation_points( int value )
{
    // move all points left each frame
    for( size_t i = 0; i < points.size(); ++i )
    {
        points[i].x -= 1;
        // wrap point around if it's moved off
        // the edge of our 100x100 area
        if( points[i].x < -50 )
        {
            points[i].x = 100 + points[i].x;
        }
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(30, animation_points, 1);
}

void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-50, 50, -50, 50, -1, 1);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    // draw
    glColor3ub( 255, 255, 255 );
    glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
    glEnableClientState( GL_COLOR_ARRAY );
    glVertexPointer( 2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Point), &points[0].x );
    glColorPointer( 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, sizeof(Point), &points[0].r );
    glPointSize( 3.0 );
    glDrawArrays( GL_POINTS, 0, points.size() );
    glDisableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
    glDisableClientState( GL_COLOR_ARRAY );

    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}

//Distance between i and j
float Distance(float x1,float y1, float z1, float x2, float y2, float z2)
{
    return (sqrt(pow(x1-x2,2) + pow(y1-y2,2) + pow(z1-z2,2)));
}

//Value of F on Ox, Oy, Oz
Point CalculateF(double d, Point a, Point b, int dt)
{
    Point F;
    float vnewx, vnewy, vnewz, xnew , ynew, znew;
    float G = 6.6742*pow(10,-11);
    float Fx = (G*a.m*b.m/pow(d,2)*(a.x-b.x)/d);
    float Fy = (G*a.m*b.m/pow(d,2)*(a.y-b.y)/d);
    float Fz = (G*a.m*b.m/pow(d,2)*(a.z-b.z)/d);

    vnewx = a.vx + Fx*dt/a.m;
    vnewy = a.vy + Fy*dt/a.m;
    vnewz = a.vz + Fz*dt/a.m;

    xnew = a.x + a.x*dt;
    ynew = a.y + a.y*dt;
    znew = a.z + a.z*dt;

    F.x = xnew;
    F.y = ynew;
    F.z = znew;
    F.vx = vnewx;
    F.vy = vnewy;
    F.vz = vnewz;
    F.m = a.m;
    return F;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // begin
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE);

    glutInitWindowSize(640,480);
    glutCreateWindow("N - body");

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    // animation points
    //glutTimerFunc(30, animation_points, 1);

    ////
    int n, t;
    cout<<"\n Number of body: ";
    cin>>n;
// move after time t
    cout<<"\n\n Time: ";
    cin>>t;
    t *= 3600;

    // random points
    for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i )
    {
    Point pt;
    pt.x = -50 + (rand() % 100);
    pt.y = -50 + (rand() % 100);
    pt.z = 0;
    pt.r = rand() % 255;
    pt.g = rand() % 255;
    pt.b = rand() % 255;
    pt.a = 255;
    points.push_back(pt);
    }    

glutMainLoop();

float d;

//#pragma omp parallel default(shared) private(i,j)
for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
{
    //#pragma omp for schedule(static)
    for (int j = 0 ; j < n ; j++)
    {
        d = Distance(points[i].x, points[i].y,points[i].z, points[j].x, points[j].y, points[j].z);
        if (d!=0)
            points[i] = CalculateF(d,points[i], points[j], t); 
    }
    pnew.push_back(points[i]);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your problem statement is not clear. So what you want is interpolate the positions of the points, such that `points[i]` moves to the position of `pnew[i]`? Within some predefined time interval? With constant speed?

Comment: yeah, speed isn't main problem! I only need draw random animation points from points[i] moves to the position of pnew[i] after input value of t! Plz help me, tks so much...

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the initial and the target positions of your points in arrays, then interpolate between them in the rendering code. To do that, you determine how much time has passed, compute a `double lambda` in the range 0.0 to 1.0 from the time, then draw the points at the position `p_start + lambda * (p_target - p_start)`.